# Navigation View moved my destination view SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationlink

I am using Navigation View to create navigation beetween my view by navigation link and i found out a problem i don't know this is bug or error in my code
first image is my view look like this in my Subview file and second when i use it to in navigation it's automatic moved like this:

[image]
[image]

This is my code on parents view:

```
struct OnboardingSet: View {
    
    private var offset : CGFloat = screenFrame.Width
    @State private var currentPage : Int = 0
    @State private var NavigationTag : Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: SigninView(),
                tag: 1,
                selection: $NavigationTag,
                label: {
                    
                    HStack {
                        OnboardingView(ImageName: Resource.Image.onboarding1, Title: "First, Truth, \nPopular Topic", ButtonTitle: "Skip", TotalPage: 3, CurrentPage: 1) {
                            NavigationTag = 1
                        }
                        OnboardingView(ImageName: Resource.Image.onboarding2, Title: "Fast, Secure, \nMost Loved By User", ButtonTitle: "Skip", TotalPage: 3, CurrentPage: 2) {
                            NavigationTag = 1
                        }
                        OnboardingView(ImageName: Resource.Image.onboarding3, Title: "Feel the \n happiness", ButtonTitle: "sign in", TotalPage: 3, CurrentPage: 3) {
                            NavigationTag = 1
                        }
                    }
                    .offset(x: currentPage == 0 ? offset : 0, y: 0)
                    .offset(x: currentPage == 2 ? -offset : 0, y: 0)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 5, coordinateSpace: .local)
                            .onEnded({ (value) in
                                if value.translation.width < 0 {
                                    if currentPage != 2 {
                                        currentPage += 1
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                if value.translation.width > 0 {
                                    if currentPage != 0 {
                                        currentPage -= 1
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    )
                })
        }
    }
    
}
```

This is my subview:

```
struct SigninView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModal = SignInViewModal()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(Resource.Image.backgroundSignIn)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .blur(radius: 4)
                .offset(x: 200, y: 10.0)
            
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Hello Unwary \n Reader")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 42))
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .padding(.top,64)
                        .padding(.leading)
                        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 16, x: 16, y: 16)
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    BlurTextFeild("Email", Text: $viewModal.Email, TextEntryType: .Open)
                        .frame(width: screenFrame.Width - 30, height: 100)
                    
                    BlurTextFeild("Password", Text: $viewModal.Password,TextEntryType: .Secure)
                        .frame(width: screenFrame.Width - 30, height: 100)
                    
                }.padding()
                
                Button(action: {
                    viewModal.AuthState = viewModal.AuthState == SignInViewModal.authState.signIn ? SignInViewModal.authState.signUp : SignInViewModal.authState.signIn
                }, label: {
                    Text(viewModal.AuthState == SignInViewModal.authState.signIn ? "Create Account" : "LogIn")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .opacity(0.5)
                        .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                })
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                }, label: {
                    ZStack {
                        
                        Blur(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))
                        
                        Color.black
                            .opacity(0.3)
                        
                        Text(viewModal.AuthState == SignInViewModal.authState.signIn ? "Sign In" : "Sign Up")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 24))
                    }.frame(width: screenFrame.Width - 100, height: 80)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                }).padding(.bottom,32)
            }.frame(width: screenFrame.Width, height: screenFrame.Height)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .frame(width: screenFrame.Width, height: screenFrame.Height + 50, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some cases, you have to make view's frame not hardcore that solve this problem but in my case problem is I added navigation view two times so I had this issue.

I removed navigation view in secondary view and that solved my issue completely.

Answer (score 2):

The provided code is not testable due to many absent dependent components, but I would recommend to remove hardcoded frames (because they make views not flexible) and relayout using only stacks/alignments/paddings.

```
            }.frame(width: screenFrame.Width - 100, height: 80)    // !!
            .cornerRadius(16)
        }).padding(.bottom,32)
    }.frame(width: screenFrame.Width, height: screenFrame.Height)   // !!
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
.frame(width: screenFrame.Width, height: screenFrame.Height + 50, alignment: .center)  // !!
```